# Incrementing numbers starting from 0000 in php

Tags: php, numbers

I need a suggestion on a function for a php counter. Is there any function to have numbers with 5 digit as 00001, or 00123… this number should be not random but have to increase the value of  a previous field.

If a number is $n=’00001’ there is a function to increase by one and get 00002 and not 2?

Thanks
F.

Comment: Why not just pad it with leading zeros?

Comment: as @j08691 suggests use an int, and then pad when you need to display it in this format.

Comment: ...and if you are starting with a string that already has leading zeros, you can do `$new = str_pad(ltrim($old, '0') + 1, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);` - note that converting a string directly to an integer if it has leading zeros may not produce the results you expect, it may be treated as an octal. Don't underestimate PHP's `++` increment operator, it is pretty clever and can actually cope with alphas as well as numerics, like [this example](http://codepad.org/joxh9qoR)

Comment: You can also use the sprintf function.
`$n = sprintf('%1$05d', $number);`

Comment: Rule of thumb: format only at the last moment (when you're displaying the data to the user).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
$n2 = str_pad($n + 1, 5, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Use [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) by adding `0`s (**third** parameter) to the left (**fourth** parameter) of the old number `$n` incremented by `1` (**first** parameter) until the length is 5 (**second** parameter).

Answer (score 4):

```
$number = 1;
$number++;
echo str_pad($number, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);  //00002
```

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, in case you are interested, you can use sprintf to pad this with 0's up to a certain number fairly easily.

```
$numbers = array(0,1,11,111,1111,11111,11111);
$padded  = array();
foreach($numbers as $num)
  $padded[] = sprintf('%1$05d', ++$num);

print_r($padded);
```

PHP almost always has numerous ways to do the same thing. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need the [`str_pad()`](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) function to add leading zeros to your indexes.

```
$new_index = str_pad($index, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Where `$index` your incrementing index in circle, `$new_index` is your index with leading zeros.