# fill a series of numbers seperated by dash or comma

Tags: php

I need to fill series of numbers where dash or comma is in use.
I'm using this code that works fine but when numbers starts with zero it's not working (the leading zero drop)

```
$str = str_replace(' ', '', '11-17,19,041244-041250);
$arr = explode(',', $str);

foreach ($arr as $elem) {
    $values = explode('-',$elem);

    if (count($values) != 1) {
        for($i = $values[0]; $i <= $values[1]; $i++) {
            $newArr[]=$i;
        }
    } else {
        $newArr[] = $elem;
    }

    print_r($newArr);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Taken from here: [Incrementing numbers starting from 0000 in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769681/incrementing-numbers-starting-from-0000-in-php)

```
<?php
$str = str_replace(' ', '', '11-17,19,041244-041250');
$arr = explode(',', $str);

foreach ($arr as $elem) {
    $values = explode('-',$elem);

    if (count($values) != 1) {
        for($i = $values[0]; $i <= $values[1]; $i++) {
            //$newArr[]=$values[0]++;
            $newArr[] = str_pad($i + 1, strlen($values[0]), 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }
    } else {
        $newArr[] = $elem;
    }

    print_r($newArr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just minor changes as it starts and ends with number+1.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
for($i=$values[0];$i<=$values[1];$i++)   $newArr[]=$i;
```

Is the reason this is happening. What you are doing wrong is feeding the initial loop value as a string. You can cast it to an integer and it should fix your problem.

i.e:

```
for($i=(int)$values[0];$i<=(int)$values[1];$i++)   $newArr[]=$i;
```

Another approach you could consider would be:

```
$newArr = array_merge($newArr, range((int)$values[0],(int)$values[1]));
```

Just make sure to initiate `$newArr = [];` prior to using that method.

Look into: http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = str_replace(' ', '', '11-17,19,041244-041250');
$arr = explode(',', $str);

foreach ($arr as $elem) {
    $values = explode('-',$elem);
    if (count($values) != 1) {
        $newArr[] = $values[0];
        for($i = $values[0]; $i < $values[1]; $i++) {
            $newArr[] = str_pad($i + 1, strlen($values[0]), 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }
    }else{
        $newArr[] = $elem;
    }    
}
    print_r($newArr);
}
```